# Elasticsearch Query for PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch, and I am trying to solve a query the best way possible. I'm using PHP so it would be helpful to get to view it in that format, but I am ok to see it in any ElasticSearch DSL.

The query I need basically has to match Any or All words in multiple fields, say for example [title, description]

But I also want to only include any documents that can be filtered by any true case (example if the Document has "either" field1 = true OR field2 = true)

So example I search for "Nike boots that are green"

So for I would like to see results that would have Nike boots and Green
so I could just do

```
'query' => [
  'query_string' => [
    'fields' => [ 'title^6', 'description^3' ],
    'query' => 'Nike boots that are green'
  ],
],
```

And I get all content that has the best score.
What I really want to add to my results are basically "filters" or "should  " that if the Document either has field 'access' == 1 OR field 'permission' == 5, how will I do that. I know now that it needs to be a boolean.

Is it possible to have both query and boolean query in the same search?

Comment: Do you mean the Elastica library when you say Elasticsearch in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the  [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query supports OR

```
'query' => [
  'query_string' => [
    'query' => 'access:1 OR permission:5'
  ],
],
```

Comment: awesome thankx Кирилл Полищук, totally worked out for me. appreciate it. Is it possible to add filters for range if needed?

Comment: or do you have a reference link for such queries in different situations?